# Find files based on glob

Tags: java, java-8

I have a glob, which might look like *.txt, in which case I want to search the current directory for text files. Or it might look like **/*.txt, in which case I want to walk the file tree to find files.

DirectoryStream does what I want when *.txt is passed in, and Files.walk works when I have **/*.txt. Is there an approach in java 8 that will work based on my glob (or rather, my PathMatcher)?

Comment: What's wrong with `Files.walk`? http://javapapers.com/java/glob-with-java-nio/

Comment: So I'm taking in a root directory and a glob-pattern. If I get \*.txt, it should just search that directory. The user indicates if they want subdirectories via the pattern, ie \*\*/\*.txt

Comment: I think I found an answer.
 walk(Path start, int maxDepth, FileVisitOption... options) 
I think I can just have an if statement and set maxDepth to 0 if necessary

Comment: Maybe an external library like https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/wildcard can help

Comment: Can `**` occur in the middle of a pattern, like `/home/steve/**/*.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, to get it to either traverse directories or not based on the pattern (note that this code uses groovy, but isn't very different from a pure java 8 solution)

```
Path src = filesystem.getPath(job.srcDir)
int numSubDirs = job.pattern.contains("**") ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : 1

        Files.walk(src, numSubDirs)
                .filter{Path path -> filesystem.getPathMatcher("glob:${job.pattern}").matches(path.getFileName())}
                .filter{Path path -> job.days ? (new Date()) - new Date(path.toFile().lastModified()) <= job.days : true}
                .each{ Path path ->
                    actions[job.action](job, path)
                    fileCount++
                }
```